# Bitwise ANDING Of Two STD_LOGIC_VECTORS

Tags: controller, vhdl, vga

Hey I was wondering if it was at all possible in VHDL to AND two `STD_LOGIC_VECTORS` together. For example, I'm writing a VHDL program that will output a character to a VGA monitor. I have a vector `PixelRow: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0)` and `PixelColumn: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0)`. What I'm trying to do is have a `STD_LOGIC` Output that takes the two pixel vectors and ANDs them with another vector eg.

```
    Output <= (PixelRow AND NOT "0000000000") OR (PixelColumn AND NOT "0000000000") OR      
              (PixelRow AND NOT "0111011111") OR (PixelColumn AND NOT "1001111111");
```

This code I'm hoping can be used to simplify the following code:

```
    Output <= ((NOT PixelRow(0) AND NOT PixelRow(1) AND NOT PixelRow(2) AND NOT   
              PixelRow(3) AND NOT PixelRow(4) AND NOT PixelRow(5) AND NOT PixelRow(6)      
              AND NOT PixelRow(7) AND NOT PixelRow(8) AND NOT PixelRow(9)))
          OR ((NOT PixelRow(0) AND PixelRow(1) AND PixelRow(2) AND PixelRow(3) AND 
              NOT PixelRow(4) AND PixelRow(5) AND PixelRow(6) AND PixelRow(7) AND 
              PixelRow(8) AND PixelRow(9)))
          OR ((NOT PixelColumn(0) AND NOT PixelColumn(1) AND NOT PixelColumn(2) AND 
              NOT PixelColumn(3) AND NOT PixelColumn(4) AND NOT PixelColumn(5) AND NOT 
              PixelColumn(6) AND NOT PixelColumn(7) AND NOT PixelColumn(8) AND NOT 
              PixelColumn(9)))
          OR ((PixelColumn(0) AND NOT PixelColumn(1) AND NOT PixelColumn(2) AND 
              PixelColumn(3) AND PixelColumn(4) AND PixelColumn(5) AND PixelColumn(6) 
              AND PixelColumn(7) AND PixelColumn(8) AND PixelColumn(9)));
```

The bigger block of code draws a box around the screen. I'm hoping there's a MUCH easier way to do this. Does anybody know how to simplify this code?

Thanks

Comment: Aha thanks, everybody for your suggestions. You were all very helpful in solving my problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you need to and/or, and what you need to reduce to a single bit.

Sure there are the `and` and `or` bit-wise vector operators which return a vector of the same size.

If you need to test equality/inequality between `PixelRow` and `"0000000000"`, then you can write either: `PixelRow /= "0000000000"` or `PixelRow = "0000000000"`.

If you need to and-reduce a vector `vect : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)` to a single bit `bit : std_logic`, the easiest way is probably to use a process:

```
process (vect) is
    variable tmp : std_logic;
begin
    tmp := '1';
    for I in 7 downto 0 loop
        tmp := tmp and vect(I);
    end loop;
    bit <= tmp;
end process;
```

If you need to do this frequently then you can define a `function` rather than a `process` to do this.

Comment: VHDL 2008 added support for reduction operators, so you could write:
`bit <= and vector;`
this would be the same as `bit <= vector(0) and vector(1) and ... and vector(n);`

Answer (score 6):

If you'd just like to bitwise AND two std_logic_vectors in VHDL it would be done like so:

```
signal a : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal b : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal x : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

x <= a AND b;
```

Google can help you out with the rest of the bitwise operators (they're very intuitive, AND, NAND, OR, NOR, NOT, etc)

If you'd like to reduce this:

```
Output <= ((NOT PixelRow(0) AND NOT PixelRow(1) AND NOT PixelRow(2) AND NOT   
...
          AND PixelColumn(7) AND PixelColumn(8) AND PixelColumn(9)));
```

Then that's very easy.

Taking a look at the AND operator truth table, you'll find that the only scenario where:

```
output <= PixelRow(0) AND PixelRow(1) AND 
    ... AND PixelRow(8) AND PixelRow(9)
```

reduces to '1' is where PixelRow = "1111111111";

SO, asynchronusly, the code could be replaced with:

```
output <= '1' when (PixelRow = "1111111111") else '0'
```

Both Column and Row at once:

```
output <= '1' when (PixelRow = "1111111111") OR
                   (PixelColumn = "1111111111") else 
          '0';
```

The principals mentioned above can be extended to other operations mentioned in the original post, such as:

```
other_value <= "0111011111";
output <= '1' when ((PixelRow AND (NOT(other_value))) = "111111111") else '0'
```

Adding the column into the equation and/or doing the operation synchronously is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like what you actually want to do is compare `PixelRow` and `PixelCol` with some numerical values?

Make it an `unsigned` vector and do something like (I made up the numbers 100 and 200 - you might be better to define integer constants for them to make your code self-documenting):

```
output <= '1' when pixelRow = 0 or pixelCol = 0 or pixelRow = 100 or pixelCol = 200
          else '0';
```

Let the synthesizer figure out the logic.